# Run shell command from child shell

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have a Unix shell script test.sh. Within the script i would like to invoke another shell and then execute the rest of the commands in the shell script from the child shell and exit

To make it clear:

### `test.sh`

```
#! /bin/bash

/bin/bash /* create child shell */

<shell-command1>
<shell-command2>
......

<shell-commandN>

exit 0
```

What my intention is to run the shell-commands1 to shell-commandN from the child shell. Kindly tell me how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup in a group, like.

```
#!/bin/bash
(
Command1
Command2
etc..
)

subshell() {
    echo "this is also within a subshell"
}

subshell
```

( and ) creates a subshell in which you run a group of commands, otherwise a simple function will do. I don't know if ( and ) is POSIX compatible.

Update: If I understand your comment correctly, you want to be using `-c` option with `bash`, like.

```
/bin/bash -c "Command1 && Command2...." &
```

Comment: Thannks Anders. But `/bin/bash -c "Command1 && Command2...."` does not show a new child shell from where the rest of the command should execute

Comment: @LinuxPenseur, Well, if you append an `&` it does :)

Answer (score 1):

From http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html here is an example:

```
#!/bin/bash
# subshell-test.sh

(
# Inside parentheses, and therefore a subshell . . .
while [ 1 ]   # Endless loop.
do
  echo "Subshell running . . ."
done
)

#  Script will run forever,
#+ or at least until terminated by a Ctl-C.

exit $?  # End of script (but will never get here).
```

Comment: but i need to have the command `/bin/bash`. That command cannot be deleted. After executing /bin/bash, a new shell will be created and i want the rest of the commands to be executed from the new shell

Comment: @LinuxPenseur: The new process is a separated instance of the father process, so I believe the code you put between `( )` to be executed by `/bin/bash`