# How to interact with new shell I logged into from script?

Tags: python, bash, shell

Not able to send commands to shell I logged into

Originally, I wrote a Python script. It was able to send commands like

```
subprocess.run(['kubectl', 'config', 'get-context'], shell=True)
```

but when it came time to get to the child shell, in this case bash, the command wouldn't run until I exited that shell and it would say things like it couldn't find the command.

I then tried to do it with the module "sh," but was also unsuccessful

I thought maybe using Python was problem and also realized my ultimate goal was to use a different shell (cypher-shell) and so skipped immediately to that with bash as the parent shell. In there I have a line that is sometimes successful, sometimes not

```
kubectl run -it --rm cypher-shell   --image=gcr.io/cloud-marketplace/neo4j-public/causal-cluster-k8s:3.4   --restart=Never   --namespace=default   --command -- ./bin/cypher-shell -u neo4j   -p "password" -a "domain.name"
```

But even when it successfully logs in it, it just hangs until I manually exit and then it runs the next commands

Note: I saw this and so, perhaps, it's not a child shell? [Run shell command from child shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658128/run-shell-command-from-child-shell)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what you are trying to do.  Is it that you wish to run a shell process and feed it commands into its `stdin`?  That can be done using simple redirection from `bash`.  Or is it that you wish to add commands to an *interactive* shell?

Comment: I'm not sure. If you're curious, perhaps you'll understand if I tell you how I achieved my goal. I wrote a bash script that sent commands to the other server's shell via the double dash. So `kubectl exec -it domain.name -- commands here` and I ran the script from Python using `subprocess.call("./filename.sh")` ... Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: That double-dash just means that what follows do not contain command-line options, most command-line programs have it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I know exactly what you are doing, but if I understand your objective correctly you want the Python program to continue to log while the script continues to run? The problem is that the logger continues to run and holds up your program. The way I would deal with that would be to run the logger as a background process.

With bash, that would be `./script.sh &` which would make it run without holding the rest of the program back from running.

Hopefully that may give you an idea! Good luck.

Comment: Hi, Dean. Thanks for the response. No. I want to keep sending commands to the cursor.
So I have a script of commands. Let's say at line 3 I enter bash (instead of being in the python shell). I want line 4 to be sent to the bash shell, but it currently waits until I leave the bash shell